# How to clear all in C?

Tags: c

I have a simple program that makes sure another program runs 10 times in a row by using the following code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  system ("shor.exe 15");   
}
```

The program `shor.exe` does indeed run 10 times; the problem is that the program is probabilistic in the sense that in one of the first steps it uses a random number generator and saves it in the variable "random" but each of the 10 runs has the same value for the variable random so I guess that it doesn't reset all variables and just uses the same generated value each run.

My question now is how do I reset/clear all the variables between each run?

Comment: You should show the code of the program that has produces the random numbers not the one you use to run it. You are most likely seeding the rng with the same seed each time you run it

Comment: Especially because a common way to initialize the seed in C is with `srand(time(NULL))` which will only change the seed once every second.

Comment: btw I wouldnt use c to start an executable, thats a job for a batch file or some scripting language

Comment: As a quick experiment, try to sleep for one second between the calls to `system`. If that fixes the issue, you know that `shor.exe` seeds its random number generator from a timer, and you simply finish your 10 runs before the timer switches its value.

Comment: check for arguments to pass for shor.exe, why are you passing 15?

Comment: Each time the program is run, it is given a clean slate; all variables are reset.  One run does not influence the next unless the program takes steps to ensure that it does (which can be done; it is just harder work). The problem is almost certainly that the program doesn't do a good job of choosing random numbers. I don't know whether Windows has the equivalent of `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` on Unix-like systems — a file-like object that can be read to get a reasonably random seed value – but it is likely that it does. Consider researching and finding it and revising `shor.exe` to use it.

Comment: thanks for the fast respons!! I looked into the code of shor.exe and they indeed used       srand(time(0));.  How would i use such a sleeper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program forgets to *seed* the randomizer. And if it does, and it uses `time(NULL)` to seed the randomizer, then they are all seeded with the same seed because they are all started at the same moment: your for loop won't wait for each program to have ended and randomizers often are determinsitic, meaning the same seed implies the same sequence of random numbers.